# Want to install Django in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, pip

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: your user doesn't have permission to write to the directory, you can use sudo for installing packages using root user. what is the output when you run `whoami` command on terminal?

Comment: `pip install --user Django`

Comment: @RajanSharma We should stop advising people to do `sudo pip install` as that will install _project_ dependencies to _system_ site-packages. Using `--user` or a virtualenv is the recommended solution.

Comment: @GinoMempin I Agree!

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, try using the `--user` flag

```
pip install --user Django
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install Django
```

or 
`pip3 install Django` for `pip3` and `python3`